# Objective-C selector overload

Tags: objective-c, selector

There are classes having some well-known selectors like UIView layer. What if someone subclasses UIView and declares his own "layer" selector for a different purpose? And then some other frameworks like UIKit itself calling layer on UIView instances. This will call "layer" on the subclass and cause crash?

Comment: Note that what you are describing applies to _any/all_ Object Oriented framework/library/foundation.  Not just Objecive-C.

Comment: Are you asking if it will cause a problem when UIKit calls the layer method on your subclass or other UIView objects?  (Very different answers, but for short they are "yes" and "no", respectively).

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I was almost certain but wanted it to be confirmed. :) Because I saw it overrode by something completely different...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never override an existing method and use it for a completely different purpose.

When you have a `UIView` subclass, override `layer` to return something entirely different and then a framework class (that is not aware of the purpose of your override) calls the `layer` method, getting back something that it didn't expect, things will go south rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

No, every instance knows what class it is, and if you create a `UIView` even after overriding something in a subclass, the `UIView` will still use its version of that method. That's pretty fundamental to inheritance -- child classes should not affect parents.

```
@interface Stuper : NSObject
- (void)layer;
@end

@implementation Stuper
- (void)layer {
     NSLog(@"superclass");
}
@end

@interface Stub : Stuper
@end

@implementation Stub
- (void)layer {    // Override layer
    NSLog(@"subclass");
}
@end
```

---

```
Stuper * p = [Stuper new];
Stub * b = [Stub new];
[p layer];    // Prints "superclass"
[b layer];    // Prints "subclass"
```

However, this can happen if you override a method in a category, which is why you should not do that. All instances of the original class will use the new version of the method, which can cause large problems, especially for framework classes.

```
@interface Stuper (BadIdea)
- (void)layer;    // Clobber layer
@end

@implementation Stuper (BadIdea)
- (void)layer {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Sucker!");
}
@end
```

---

```
Stuper * p = [Stuper new];
[p layer];    // Almost certainly doesn't do what the caller was expecting
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to subclass a framework object, the first place you should look is the class reference provided by Apple.

[Click here for the `UIView` class reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816).

In the class reference, there is a section titled **Subclassing Notes** that contains important information about subclassing.  This section contains information about which methods **must** be overridden, which methods **should** be overridden, and which methods should **never** be overridden.

In this case, the `layer` method is not mentioned, however under **Methods to Override** it has this:

> - layerClass - Implement this method only if you want your view to use    a different Core Animation layer for its backing store. For
>     example,    if you are using OpenGL ES to do your drawing, you would
>     want to    override this method and return the CAEAGLLayer class.

Looking into that a little further, under the `layerClass` property description, it has this:

> **layerClass**
>   Returns the class used to create the layer for instances of this class.
>
> `+ (Class)layerClass`
>
> **Return Value**
>   The class used to create the view’s Core Animation layer.
>
> **Discussion**
>   This method returns the CALayer class object by default.  Subclasses can override this method and return a different
>   layer class as needed. For example, if you use OpenGL ES to do your
>   drawing, you would override this method and return the class object
>   for the CAEAGLLayer class.
>
> This method is called only once early in the creation of the view in 
>   order to create the corresponding layer object.

So, this tells us that you **can** change the class that `layer` is expected to return, however it must be a "different layer class" (i.e. a subclass of `CALayer`).  Lots of other functions interact with the layer when laying it out, resizing, etc, etc and you will have major problems if you don't follow their guidelines.

**Note:**
All of this applies to your subclassed objects.  It in no way touches or applies to the parent class (`UIView` in this case) when you make changes in a subclass, so you don't have to worry about breaking UIView objects, just your own subclassed objects potentially causing crashes and undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like the basis of Object Oriented Language. You pick a class that is similar to your intentions then create a subclass of it and manipulate it to do what you want it to do. Most of the time though you need to tell your compiler you are overriding that feature of the class so that it doesn't call the base class.

Comment: You don't need to specifically tell the compiler that a method is an override in Objective-C.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that for me. I was thinking while i was posting that that Objective-C = C#... i was WAAAAAY off. Sorry about misleading information